# Java equivalent to SECOND() function in Excel

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to convert the Excel function `SECOND()` (described [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SECOND-function-740d1cfc-553c-4099-b668-80eaa24e8af1)) in Java.

Please help if you know a Java function that does the same.

Comment: It might help if you were to [edit] your question and describe the context in which you would be using this function. For example, will you be working with true Java date/time values? Please see [ask] for more tips on how to ask a high-quality question.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question more readable. I actually understand it better myself. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, dates and times is stored as a `double`, with the fractional part being the time of day (see [Dates And Times In Excel](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm)).

So, to get seconds, you multiply by number of seconds in a day, and get the remainder on division by 60:

```
double time = 42369.546594213; // 2015-12-31 13:07:05.740
int seconds = (int)(time * 86400 % 60); // 5
```

Or, if you want all time components:

```
int hours   = (int)(time * 24 % 24);         // 13
int minutes = (int)(time * 1440 % 60);       // 7
int seconds = (int)(time * 86400 % 60);      // 5
int millis  = (int)(time * 86400000 % 1000); // 740
```